# How to install SOLR 7.2.1 + Tomcat on Windows?

Tags: tomcat, solr

I'm looking at the SOLR wiki (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat) on how to install SOLR on Tomcat, but they talk about a WAR file and that was removed on the latest version.

Does anyone know how to setup it up without the war file? I want to keep SOLR running as a service on my windows server.

I do have SOLR setup and working but I'm running on cmd line `solr start` but I need to have it running all the time as a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to follow the official [guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/installing-solr.html), it has quite a lot of details. Regarding the Tomcat thing, it is not obsolete, and recommended approach is to run Solr on top of Jetty.

Regarding running Solr as a service all time,

> If you are running Windows, you can start Solr by running `bin\solr.cmd`
>   This will start Solr in the background, listening on port 8983.

More example on how to start Solr - https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/solr-control-script-reference.html#starting-and-stopping

Comment: I did follow the setup on that guide and I have my SOLR server working. I will keep it running on Jetty since that is the recommended approach.

Comment: This is like nobody upvotes and marks good answers that helped. Although such questions can be marked UNSALVAGEABLE because they aren't about programming but tutorial requests.

Comment: @EugèneAdell unfortunately, it happens, people sometimes upvote answers, but forgot to accept it and vise-versa. It's especially hurts if you spend several hours helping

Comment: @Mysterion it happened many times, not long ago 3/4 hours of debugging and the guy even not said thanks.